# How to run more than one puttycm application process on the same Windows box?

Tags: windows, putty

I have tried running puttycm on 2 separate Windows RDP sessions on the same Windows server and it wouldn't allow me to run more than one.

I don't understand why I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the general option to "Allow multiple instances"
Tools Menu > Options > General > Tick on "Allow multiple instances"